# Installed pip packages are not available when deploying the container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, pip, openshift

Inside my Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y git

RUN groupadd -g 1001 myuser
RUN useradd -u 1001 -g 1001 -ms /bin/bash myuser
USER 1001:1001
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser requirements.txt ./

ENV PYTHONPATH="/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:.:$PYTHONPATH"
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser  . .

ENV PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin/:$PATH"

ENV HOME=/home/myuser
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=1
EXPOSE 8001
CMD [ "python3.7", "app.py" ]
```

During the build, `pip list` displays all the libraries correctly:

```
basicauth       0.4.1
pip             21.1.1
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2019.1
PyYAML          5.1.1
requests        2.22.0
setuptools      56.0.0
six             1.16.0
urllib3         1.25.11
wheel           0.36.2
```

But once OpenShift deploys the container, I only get the following libraries installed:

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/myuser/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.1.1
setuptools 56.0.0
wheel      0.36.2
```

The CMD command runs as expected, but none of the packages are installed...

```
Traceback (most recent call last :
File "app.py", line 16, in ‹module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Please post the complete Dockerfile somewhere. Most likely this is something related to the shell things are running in, `RUN` command use a shell context while an array `CMD` execs directly with no shell process.

Also you don't need to do any of this, just install things globally as root like normal, it's a container not a VM or workstation.

Comment: Hi @coderanger, thank you. I have updated the question with the entire Dockerfile and some more information. The weird part is that this only happens when running on OpenShift, if I build locally everything works as expected and the libraries are installed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're installing packages as the runtime user? That's actually less safe than installing them normally.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I move USER myuser after pip install? @coderanger

Comment: The weird part is that when I build locally, the issue doesn't happen. This is only happening when I run on OpenShift/Kubernetes

Comment: I'll put a more normal version of this Dockerfile in an answer, one sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232149/discussion-between-eduardo-morales-and-coderanger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A revised Dockerfile more in line with standard practices:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt update && \ 
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends git && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=1
USER nobody
CMD [ "python3.7", "app.py" ]
```

I combined the initial `RUN` layers for a smaller image, and cleaned up the apt lists before exiting the layer. Packages are installed globally as root, and then only after that it changes to runtime user. In this case unless you very specifically need a homedir, I would stick with `nobody`/65534 as the standard way to express "low privs runtime user".

Remember that OpenShift overrides the container-level `USER` info https://www.openshift.com/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids

Comment: that works but now i have no write access inside the docker. I get permission denied. How can I fix that? thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing files in the image outside of /tmp, which you should still have access to. If you need storage, use a volume, either an emptyDir or normal Persistent Volume.